# Start ASP.NET 5 Web Application Visual Studio 2015 in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, visual-studio-2015

I tried to start my site in Azure on Visual Studio 2015 CTP6. I registered into Azure, created my web-app in https://manage.windowsazure.com, upload a publications profile, create my project in VS and publish it with import this profile. But when i entered into my site in Azure, i had an error: "Server Error in '/' Application.". You can see it here http://mcc-dance-azure.azurewebsites.net 
When i create project and choose ASP.NET 5, i cannt to mark checkbox "Microsoft Azure Host in the cloud".If i start my site on local server - it started normally. And i installed Azure SDK. Help me please to solve my problem. Thanks you.

Comment: which type of web app you created in Azure? You should create just empty web app, not ASP.NET.

Comment: web app - create - runtime application - web app - quick create. I created such way. As you can see, it was empty

Comment: I use Preview Azure: Create -> Web + Mobile -> Web App. I got the same error when I created ASP.NET Empty Web App. But then I created just Web App, deployed from VS and it's working: http://asp50.azurewebsites.net/

Comment: in VS i created Visual C# - ASP.NET Web app. I dont have just Web App there

Comment: Web App in Azure. In VS I choose ASP.NET 5 Starter Web Template.

Comment: as i wrote above, in Azure i jsut create "Web app"

Comment: then I don't know. See similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30017444/deploy-asp-net-5-app-as-windows-azure-website

Comment: Alex, thanks you. I create "starter" and it helped me